# FSImage efficient to read, but unsuitable for making small incremental updates

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

**Introduction**

**Aim:** Understanding why HDFS' NameNode consists of FSImage and EditLog.

According to [this article](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/03/a-guide-to-checkpointing-in-hadoop/) the `EditLog` is used to make small incremental updates like renaming a single file as `FSImage` is efficient to read, but unsuitable for making small incremental updates.

**Question**

Why is FSImage efficient to read, but unsuitable for making small incremental updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifications of FSImage require **random writes** to disk, which are slow operations.

EditLog uses **sequential writes**, which are fast.

This is common pattern for many databases and filesystems: instead of changing real data, which is situated in the different areas of disk, changes recorded in the log file first. Log file can be written and read sequentially, which increase the speed of operations.